# SQL way to get number of people that have seen order of name_pages (rule2) & (rule3) without seen another page using id in between

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Table name: DocumentationBook

| id | name_page |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | rule1 |
| 2 | rule2 |
| 1 | rule3 |
| 2 | rule3 |
| 3 | rule2 |
| 3 | rule3 |

I have tried to do this,

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM DocumentationBook
where name_page = "rule2" OR name_page = "rule3"
```

but it doesnt look right since i would like to show rule2 and rule3 following each other, or if there's a method to give order of pages seen i would appreciate it so much.

Comment: We are talking about order of visits. Therefore, an additional column is required to tell the visiting order, could you specify a column related to visiting order per user in the post?

Comment: What is your expected count in above example ? `2` or `1`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba355f2/6) using your table data;

The following query shall return you the expected result.

```
select count(distinct id) as count_of_people
from DocumentationBook 
where id in (
  select id 
  from DocumentationBook 
  where name_page = 'rule2'
) and id in (
  select id 
  from DocumentationBook 
  where name_page = 'rule3'
);
```

Output :

```
count_of_people
2
```

> without seen another page using id in between

If you want to add this condition; you can add as

```
and id not in (
  select id 
  from DocumentationBook 
  where name_page in ('rule4', 'rule5', 'rule6')
);
```

Here rule numbers you can decide as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it using `WITH` clause

```
with cte as (
  select id
  from DocumentationBook
  where name_page in ('rule2', 'rule3')
  group by id 
  having count(1) = 2
),
cte2 as (
  select id
  from DocumentationBook
  where name_page not in ('rule2', 'rule3')
)
select count(1)
from cte 
where id not in (select id from cte2)
```

First cte to get ids that have seen **rule2** and **rule3**

Second cte to get ids that have seen other rules except **rule2** and **rule3**

Then we get only ids from fist cte that are not on cte2.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/j83Qmvdp)